# What does status "in progress" mean on SharePoint Tasks?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, approval-process

I am new on SharePoint and I want to know what does the status `In Progress` mean on SharePoint Designer 2010 Approval Workflow's Tasks, because tasks, normally, begin with status `Not Started` and any option the user choose will set its status to `Completed`. But recently I found in the task list some tasks with status `In Progress` and I don't have idea why they took that status.

Could some of you clear my mind?

Comment: Can you mark your question as answered, It keeps popping up in the Unanswered list

Answer (score 1):

In Progress means that task is still being executed, somebody working on it.

If you see the a standard task list, it has be default following status:

- Not Started
- In Progress
- Completed
- Deferred
- Waiting on someone else

read these office article to help you understand more:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-task-process-editor-for-approval-workflows-8680b4a4-36b1-441c-b070-e515976078aa

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-HA101859249.aspx#_Toc261009031

Comment: Hi Waqas, the same goes for you. There's nothing to modify in the task. Users just can press one of three buttons: Approve, Reject and Request Changes. Whatever the user press will set the status to "Completed".

Answer (score 0):

It is as it says - the status "In Progress" is there so the person working on it can indicate that they actually are working on it.  If used consistently it gives managers a better idea of what is done versus what people are currently doing versus what is in the pipeline.

Comment: Hi Andarta, thanks for your answer, but the problem is that there's nothing the user can do rather than approve, reject or request changes. Any option the user choose will set the task's status to "Completed". Before the user summit the task by pressing one of the three buttons previously mentioned, it will remains in "Not started".

Answer (score 0):

I think it is some type of bug in the workflow.  I get "In Progress" on some of my workflow created task entries right away, before anyone would have the opportunity to open the task. This seems most likely to happen when I have more than two tasks created from the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested with Approve/Reject but SharePoint sets the Status field from "Not Started" to "In Progress" when the % Complete (PercentComplete) value is changed from 0 to another value.

Answer (score 0):

in Approval workflow ,task "In Progress" means , task is assign to particular person / Manager , but not yet approved or rejected,

In Progress is stage before approved or rejected,